# Figure of subfigures with different heights

Tags: graphics

I have a figure with two eps subfigures, I am using the subfigure package, the problem is that those figures have different heights, is the there a way to display them both with the same height?

```
\begin{figure}[htb] 
 \centering
  \subfigure[Expanding]
  {\includegraphics[scale =0.4]{./figs/figure1.eps}}
  \subfigure[Retracting]
  {\includegraphics[scale =0.4]{./figs/figure1.eps}}
  \caption{Expanding and retracting trajectories}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: In the optional argument to `\includegraphics`, specify `height=<xx>cm` instead of `scale`...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Note: the `subfigure` package is deprecated. Use the `subcaption` package instead.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, you can alter the size of a graphic not only in a relative (`scale`) way but also by setting an absolute height or width

```
\begin{figure}[htb] 
 \centering
  \subfigure[Expanding]
  {\includegraphics[height = 5 cm]{./figs/figure1}}
  \subfigure[Retracting]
  {\includegraphics[height = 5 cm]{./figs/figure1}}
  \caption{Expanding and retracting trajectories}
\end{figure}
```

Scaling maintains the aspect ratio of the graphic, so you don't need to worry about the widths here.